# Why are my columns not displaying width the alignment I set with \newcolumntype

Tags: tables

I am adding a table where I want to specify the width and alignment of each column. I have done this via \newcolumn but the alignment isn't working as expected. In the image below you can see that the second and fourth column are left aligned instead of the \raggedright I set in my code for the \newcolumntype.

I am using sweave with r to create the latex file and my texnic installation is broken so I can't debug great at the moment.

Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcolumntype{T}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{1.7cm}}
\newcolumntype{O}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{3.4cm}}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}

\begin{table}[!h]   
    \begin{tabular}{lMTM}
  \hline
 & \textbf{Total Population}& \textbf{Carers} & \textbf{Carers as a Percentage of Population}\\ 
  \hline
  Males  & 210& 21 & 10.0  \\
    Females  & 209& 18 & 8.6  \\ 
      Both Sexes  & 419& 39 & 9.3  \\ 
     \hline
       \href{http://www.test.com}{Source} & &
\end{tabular}

\caption{Carers by Gender, 2022}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: raggedright _means_ left alignment (that is the left edge is straight, the right edge is ragged)

Comment: You example does not compile. At least `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` are missing. Please always try to show a [minimal *working* example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). *Working* usually means, that is can be compiled without changes.